# How do I update a specific property of an object in an arraylist in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a system that I'm making for a school project, with clients, appointments, etc. I'm just struggling to figure out how I can update the LocalDateTime appointment variable that I have setup for each client, I know how to make a new client with one, but just can't figure out how to update it.

```
ArrayList<Client> clients = Client.inputClientsFromFile();

LocalDateTime tempappointment;
int yearint = Integer.parseInt(year.getText());
int monthint = Integer.parseInt(month.getText());
int dayint = Integer.parseInt(day.getText());
int hourint = Integer.parseInt(hour.getText());
int minuteint = Integer.parseInt(minutes.getText());
tempappointment = LocalDateTime.of(yearint,monthint,dayint,hourint,minuteint);
```

I have written this to get the localdatetime from textboxes and this

```
public LocalDateTime getAppointment() {
        return nextappointment;
    }

    /**
     * @param nextappointment
     */
    public void setAppointment(LocalDateTime nextappointment) {
        this.nextappointment = nextappointment;
```

when initiliazing the client object in the arraylist.

Comment: Note: you probably don't want to use `LocalDateTime` if there's any chance the timezone on the client may differ to the one on server. Secondly, just invoke a setter on your `Client` instances to mutate them? Not a very clear question though...

Comment: Hi!

As Mena wrote, you just need to add a setter for the appointment in class `Client` and iterate on clients in your method `setAppointment` to set the new value:

        `for(Client client: clients)   
          client.setAppointment(nextappointment);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Client.setAppointment`

For a specific client:

```
LocalDateTime tempappointment = LocalDateTime.of(yearint, monthint, dayint, hourint, minuteint);
clients.get(0).setAppointment(tempappointment);
```

For all

```
for (Client client : clients) {
    client.setAppointment(tempappointment);
}
```